# Unable to install new Eclipse Helios software

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-3.6, helios

I have a problem downloading new software via the "Install New Software..." dialog of Eclipse Helios.
It used to work a few weeks ago, but now I get the following error when I try to visit the official Helios site.

> org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException
>
> Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios.

This is what I get in the error log:

```
eclipse.buildId=M20110210-1200
java.version=1.6.0_20
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_DK
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product


Error
Thu Apr 21 12:56:41 CEST 2011
Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios.

org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException: Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.CompositeMetadataRepositoryFactory.load(CompositeMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:746)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.ProvisioningUI.loadMetadataRepository(ProvisioningUI.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.model.MetadataRepositoryElement.getMetadataRepository(MetadataRepositoryElement.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.model.MetadataRepositoryElement.getRepository(MetadataRepositoryElement.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.model.MetadataRepositoryElement.getQueryable(MetadataRepositoryElement.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.QueryProvider.getQueryDescriptor(QueryProvider.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.model.QueriedElement.fetchChildren(QueriedElement.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.model.MetadataRepositoryElement.fetchChildren(MetadataRepositoryElement.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.model.RemoteQueriedElement.fetchDeferredChildren(RemoteQueriedElement.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.DeferredTreeContentManager$1.run(DeferredTreeContentManager.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios is not a valid repository location.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.CompositeMetadataRepositoryFactory.load(CompositeMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:113)
    ... 15 more
```

I have used wireshark to see exactly what eclipse does when I request the update site, and I have discovered that it does a HTTP GET request on the host download.eclipse.org, for the page "/releases/helios/p2.index" (without quotes) and that it gets a 404 error from the webserver.
This is what I get when I navigate to http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios/p2.index as well.

Does anyone have the same problem? Do I have something in my settings mixed up? Does anyone have an idea to solve my problem? or do you guys need some more info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [bug 341665](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=341665) presents a similar case and has the workaround of [using a **mirror**](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/eclipse/index.html):

> > I found where the problem is. I'm here in China, and I can't access
> >     http://www.gtlib.gatech.edu/pub/eclipse/releases/helios/, where http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios/compositeContent.jar is redirected to, because our government has blocked the access to http://www.gtlib.gatech.edu/*
> >
> > So please change a repository to help us developers in China. Thank you.
>
> [reply] [-] Comment 5 shining366@gmail.com 2011-04-15 20:47:08 EDT
>
> I find a workaround:
>   use http://mirror.neu.edu.cn/eclipse/releases/helios/ instead of http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios

Note, as described in [bug 325299](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=325299):

> There is an ordering for the files that we look for when we connect to a server:
>
> - `compositeContent.jar`
> - `compositeContent.xml`
> - `content.jar`
> - `content.xml`
> - `site.xml`

Comment: As of bug 341665, I would really like a real solution, rather than a quick-fix using a mirror (if it works). This is primarily because this is not the only site that the installer has the problem with.
As of bug 325299, none of the above is contacted before a http request for "p2.index" fails.
I see one GET request for /releases/helios/p2.index that fails in a 404 response.

Comment: And just after I see a HEAD response for /releases/helios/compositeContent.jar that is not responded as I can see.

Comment: @creen: I agree with you: an actual solution would be preferable.

Comment: tried: http://mirror.neu.edu.cn/eclipse/releases/helios, install works now. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

add this line to
  eclipse.ini

-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true